# On screen keyboard malfunctioning on login screen

Tags: gdm

The problem is the login screen is divided into two showing a onscreen keyboard like thing in the left side and the same magnified in the other side. Also it is giving the error message as `/usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256`

Comment: Did you want that onscreen keyboard to show, or are you just trying to get rid of it? Do you only see the onscreen keyboard and no user name prompt? Do you have any idea how the onscreen keyboard got there (it sure isn't in the default installation)? What happens if you type? Where exactly did you see that error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recenly a friend of mine reported a similar problem which was due to "mistakenly" turning on the `screen magnifier` and `on-screen keyboard` from the accessibility preferences. Apparently this is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/594145).

If this is (a part of your problem) you can try out the fix recommended [here](http://wwww.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9271557&postcount=17).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you do not wish to actually uninstall the screen magnifier or on-screen keyboard, here are some commands to disable them in GDM.

If you are able to log-in to the desktop, you can run them from a terminal or press `Alt-F2` to get the run dialog, check "Run in terminal" and enter the commands there.

If you can't get to your desktop, press `Ctr-Alt-F1` to drop to a console, login, enter the commands. You may have to restart to see the effects.

Disable screen magnifier in GDM:

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_magnifier_enabled --type bool --set false
```

Disable on-screen keyboard in GDM:

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_keyboard_enabled --type bool --set false
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo killall magnifier` from a terminal (or a tty if you cannot login), return to the login screen and  deselect the magnifier option.