# Disabling assistive technologies during login

Tags: login-screen, accessibility

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 10.04.

My daughter was playing with the keyboard on the login screen, and it seems she activated some assistive technologies because now the screen is split vertically and the right side shows a magnified version of the left side. Plus, there's a screen keyboard.

The way the screen is split makes it impossible for me to disable the assistive stuff from the toolbar at the bottom, since I can only see part of it.

I don't know if it's a bug or what, because I'd guess I could see the entire bar on the right (magnified) side just by moving the mouse there, but I can't.

I can't even type on the login screen, nor use the on-screen keyboard... Good thing I have auto-login activated, so I can still use the computer, but I can't switch users.

So, does anyone know how to get the normal login screen back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From: [gdm - On screen keyboard malfunctioning on login screen - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4314/on-screen-keyboard-malfunctioning-on-login-screen/5185#5185)

Disable screen magnifier in GDM:

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_magnifier_enabled --type bool --set false
```

Disable on-screen keyboard in GDM:

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_keyboard_enabled --type bool --set false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting gdm to the default values

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /desktop
```

Comment: I'm sure this would work too, but Andrew's solution doesn't reset all configurations. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying disable it at *Preferences -> Assistive technologies* ? Another way would be to disable it from start up on *Preferences -> Start Up Applications* and untick the option relative to Assistive technologies.

Comment: It wouldn't work because those happen after login, but thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 0):

In 11.10 start onboard from terminal, press the bottom right button that has three lines over it (Snippets), press preferences (left side). From Onboard preferences un check "Show Onboard when unlocking the screen".