# Screen magnifier wrecks login screen — how to get rid of it?

Tags: 10.04, gdm, login-screen

In the Ubuntu / GNOME login screen, I tried some of the different accessibility settings out of curiosity. Big mistake!

Enabling the "use screen magnifier" (or whatever) option breaks down the view horribly, and makes it impossible to even access the settings again:

[image]
[image]

Yes, I tried to access every corner of the screen using the mouse, but there's just chaos everywhere. Fortunately, I can still log in (pressing "Esc" makes the normal login dialog appear on the left-hand monitor).

My question is, how to disable the "magnifier" option **outside of the login screen itself**? (By editing some config file perhaps?) I don't care about getting the magnifier mode to work properly - just make it go away altogether, please.

Comment: that is... wow...

Comment: Related, but not duplicate, question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4314/on-screen-keyboard-malfunctioning-on-login-screen/5185

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want it, remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-mag
```

There's probably a way to turn it off but I can't see anything particularly bad about this seeing as you don't want it.

That will probably take `gnome-accessibility` with it but, again, that shouldn't cause any problems. If you need anything `gnome-accessibility` installed (dasher, orca, gok, mousetweaks, etc) you can mark them as a manual install in Synaptic.

Edit: If you just want to turn it off on the login screen (but use it elsewhere), fire this off from a terminal:

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_magnifier_enabled --type bool --set false
```

Comment: Yes, the `gconftool-2` command worked. (I did end up also removing `gnome-mag`, and it didn't take any other package with it.) Thanks again!