# starting up and log in

Tags: 12.04

when i start up our computer (where you put in your password) i know have a split screen. think my daughter did something!! once you have logged in it goes back to a normal screen. how can i get rid of this split screen when i 1st. turn on our p.c. you also cannot type in the numbers u have to use the keyboard that pops up on the right side with the mouse. u cannot type in the numbers? please help i have no clue what to do!!

Comment: What do you mean by “split screen”? (Maybe take a photo?) I don't understand the part about numbers, what happens when you type a number, and is that on the main keyboard area or on the numeric keypad? You should ask these as separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the screen magnifier in GDM:

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_magnifier_enabled --type bool --set false
```

Disable the on-screen keyboard:

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_keyboard_enabled --type bool --set false
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4314/on-screen-keyboard-malfunctioning-on-login-screen/5185#5185)